# Can't compile Gatsby.js project after node.js update

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to run in VSCode terminal gatsby develop and get

ERROR #11903  COMPILATION

There was an unhandled error during compilation for . Please run the command with the --verbose flag again.

Error: Error opening directory
not finished compile gatsby files - 0.834s

Node version 17.7.1

I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Please... share a minimum relevant source code, details, trials, etc. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've got a few older Gatsby projects that run on previous versions of node (12 and 14). Rather than upgrade locally I use the older versions of node for those project.

I use the following package to keep it easy: https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Enter `n` in your CL and select the version of `node` you want to use for that project. When you are done and working on current projects switch `node` back to 17+ by typing `n` and reloading the current version.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same error and what worked for me was to delete the /.cache folder and the /public folder. After that the builds were fine again.